# How can I know the dimensions of a photo when uploading in PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

When I upload a photo to my Rails application using PaperClip how can I know the dimensions (width & Height) of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Geometry

In your model:

```
before_save :set_dimensions

def set_dimensions
  tempfile = self.local_avatar.queued_for_write[:original]

  unless tempfile.nil?
    dimensions = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(tempfile)
    self.width = dimensions.width
    self.height = dimensions.height
  end
end
```

You need to change local_avatar.  And have width and height column in your model.

source: [link text](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aoGiJ2hOYhEYJ%3aroberto.peakhut.com/2010/01/14/paperclip_recipes/+paperclip+get+image+dimension&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca)